# what is the time complexity of this pascal program?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, pascal

```
Function what(x, n:integer): integer:
Var
    value : integer
begin
    value := 1
    if n > 0 then
    begin
        if n mod 2 =1 then
            value := value * x;
        value := value * what(x*x, n div 2);
    end;
    what := value;
end;
```

---

This computes *`xn`* and has time complexity `O(log N)`.

Please explain about time complexity, and how is it `O(log N)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reasonably simple. At each recursion level, you call the next level, passing in *half* of `n`:

```
what(x*x, n div 2);
```

Since it's that value that controls how many calls are made, it's an `O(log N)` complexity.

For example, if you started with `64`, you would call it with `64`, `32`, `16`, `8`, `4`, `2`, `1` and `0` (eight times). Starting with `128` would result only in *one* extra level of recursion.

---

If you think about a similar (non-recursive) case, it may become clearer:

```
function oLogN(n):
    while n > 0:
        n = truncate(n / 2)
```

That's basically what your code boils down to, with different values of `n` taking a different number of `steps` as per:

```
                              SEQUENCE
    n   steps   lowest n          | highest n (if different)
-----   -----   ------------------+-------------------------
    0       0                   0 |
    1       1                1, 0 |
  2-3       2             2, 1, 0 |                  3, 1, 0
  4-7       3          4, 2, 1, 0 |               7, 3, 1, 0
 8-15       4       8, 4, 2, 1, 0 |           15, 7, 3, 1, 0
16-31       5   16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0 |       31, 15, 7, 3, 1, 0
32-63       6              ... and so on
```